# Explanation of a proof about continuity in Spivak's Calculus

Tags: calculus, proof-explanation

I can't see the "**it follows that**" part of the following proof in Spivak's Calculus book:

> Given that $f$ is continous at $b$, there is a $\delta>0$ such that;
>   if $|x-b|<\delta$ then $|f(x)-f(b)|<\varepsilon/2$. It follows that, if
>   $|x-b|<\delta$ and $|y-b|<\delta$ then $|f(x)-f(y)|<\varepsilon$.

I have tried the following:

$$|f(x)-f(y)|=|f(x)-f(b)+f(b)-f(y)|\geq|f(x)-f(b)|-|f(y)-f(b)|$$

But I couldn't move on. Could you show me why is the above statement true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**

Use the triangle inequality

$$|f(x)-f(y)|\le |f(x)-f(b)|+|f(y)-f(b)|$$

Comment: $|f(x)-f(y)|=|f(x)-f(b)+f(b)-f(y)|\leq|f(x)-f(b)|+|f(b)-f(y)|=|f(x)-f(b)|+|f(y)-f(b)|$ right?